# PHP_SQL query not returning right answer

Tags: sql, arrays, image, path

First I would like to know how to display an image in PHP just by using the path of the image? without using BLOB.

AND

I have a table in my database which is layed out this way..

columns : i1 i2 i3 i4  i5 i6 i7 i8

each field hold a value or is empty.

I would basically want to display the values of i5 i6 i7 i8 according to what is in i1 i2 i3 i4.

For e.g:

i1=a i2=b i3=e i4=q  i5=g i6=l i7= i8=

For this case i would like g and l to be displayed. But i want the values to be stored in an array.

I tried doing:

```
$list = array(g,l)
$query = " SELECT i5, i6, i7, i8  FROM Table WHERE i1 AND i2 AND i3 AND i4 IN ('$list') ";
$s = mysql_query($query);
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($s)){
    $r_1 = $data['i5'];
    $r_2 = $data['i6'];
    $r_3 = $data['i7'];
    $r_4 = $data['i8'];         
}
echo "$r_1  $r_2 $r_3  $r_4"`
```

Which is not working even if i do `$list[0]`

Help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Error messages? Not the output you expect?

Comment: nothing is returned @BrendanLong

Comment: How are you actually doing your query? Can you show us the full code?

Comment: Have you checked the return value of [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)? It should return `FALSE` if there's an error, but you're not checking for it. Also, the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, with a giant red box on every page of documentation, saying not to use them..

Comment: I dont really understand, wht do you mean `mysql_*`

Comment: Any function starting with `mysql_` is deprecated and should not be used. See the warning at the top of this page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 2):

First I would like to know how to display an image in PHP just by using the path of the image? without using BLOB.

> You don't display images in PhP, you display it in html. If you've got the path then simply generate an img tag in html with src attribute set to path :

```
<img src="whatever your path is" alt="My Image" />
```

Blobs are used to store images (actually big binary data, images, movies, ...) directly in the DB.

Comment: could you show me an example, tried to look for tutorial but in vain. thanks @Bartdude

Comment: A tutorial to what ? An image tag in HTML ?

Comment: Please update your question and provide more details. What have you tried ? With which result ? Which info do you have in your DB ? Where are these "paths" stored ?

Comment: I was doing it using BLOB before, but i wanted to learn to do it using the path. Couldn't find much about it so i asked here. And thanks for your reply

Comment: sorted it out. Thanks for the help @Bartdude

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = mysql_query($query);
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($s)){
```

You're not checking if there's an error during the query. From [the documentation for `mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.

So do:

```
$s = mysql_query($query);
if($s === FALSE) {
    // Do something to handle the error here, possibly calling die()
}
```

Next problem, what if there's no results? Your variables would all be empty. You can test for that:

```
if(empty($r_1)) {
    echo "Oops, I guess we didn't get any results";
    // die()?
}
```

What if we get more than one row of results? I'm not sure how your program should handle this.

And finally, I think your SQL query isn't doing what you think it's doing:

```
SELECT i5, i6, i7, i8  FROM Table WHERE i1 AND i2 AND i3 AND i4 IN ('$list')
```

This will give you `i5`, `i6`, `i7`, and `i8` when `i1` is true, `i2` is true, `i3` is true, and `i4` is equal to the string `$list`. If you want find results where all of them are in the list, you'll need to do multiple `IN` statements, and you'll need to pass `$list` as a list, not a string. You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition) for how to construct the query string to pass a list to MySQL.

Also note that the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, and you should really learn to use PDO or the `mysqli_*` functions. It won't take very much time, and secure database access is *much* easier with them.

Comment: Thanks, was thinking about using learning PDO, I will soon. I had a look at your link, but when you say i will need multiple `IN`statement do you mean this way `WHERE $i1 IN ($list) AND $i2 IN ($list)...` @BrendanLong

Comment: @StringerB Yes. Except just putting $list is incredibly dangerous and probably won't work.